# Spring LDAP search Query- And filter returning duplicate response

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

Trying to search a user by lastName in a Directory. Using the follwing query

**AndFilter andFilter = new AndFilter();
andFilter.append(new EqualsFilter(LDAPAttributeConstants.LAST_NAME, userInformation.getLastName()));
List searchList = ldapTemplate.search(appContainer, andFilter.encode(), controls, new UserDetailsMapper());**

Getting multiple duplicate values of the same user in response. Cheacked the directory and only one such user is present. How to stop the duplicate values returned? and also the other users with the same lastname are not displayed at all...is something wrong with the query... ?.. Kindly help

Eg response got:
***0: {
"userId": "TestA123"
"firstName": "abc"
"lastName": "def"
"emailId": "abcdef@gmail.com"
"guid": "b%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FrkUA1%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252xQABAeKAziw%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D"
}-
1: {
"userId": "TestA123"
"firstName": "abc"
"lastName": "def"
"emailId": "abcdef@gmail.com"
"guid": "b%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FrkUA1%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252xQABAeKAziw%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D"
}-
2:  {
"userId": "TestA123"
"firstName": "abc"
"lastName": "def"
"emailId": "abcdef@gmail.com"
"guid": "b%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FrkUA1%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252xQABAeKAziw%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D"
}-
3:  {
"userId": "TestA123"
"firstName": "abc"
"lastName": "def"
"emailId": "abcdef@gmail.com"
"guid": "b%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FrkUA1%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252xQABAeKAziw%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D"
}***

Comment: Check your directory again. The search will only return the items returned by the directory server.

Comment: well yes, it should...but the directory contains no such duplicate entries..i have checked it...the search results in duplicates of a single user only

Comment: Try to extract the distinguished name of each entry returned by the search.